# Camera Flash with OpenCV3.0.0 Android not working

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera, flashlight

I'm writing a code using `opencv` video streaming, and i want to open the camera flash when first opening the camera. i have implemented a new class that is extended from `JavaCameraView` but the app crashes when i cal this line:

```
mOpencvCameraView.setEffect(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
```

the Class is As the Following:
**My Code**

```
public class CameraCustomize extends JavaCameraView  implements Camera.PictureCallback {
private String mPictureFileName;

public CameraCustomize(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
public List<String> getEffectList() {
    return mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedFlashModes();
}
public boolean isEffectSupported() {
    return (mCamera.getParameters().getFlashMode() != null);
}
public String getEffect() {
    return mCamera.getParameters().getFlashMode();
}
public void setEffect(String effect) {
    mCamera.getParameters();// here where i get the Error
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    params.setFlashMode(effect);
    mCamera.setParameters(params);

}
public List<Camera.Size> getResolutionList() {
    return mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
}
public void setResolution(int w, int h) {
    disconnectCamera();
    mMaxHeight = h;
    mMaxWidth = w;
    connectCamera(getWidth(), getHeight());
}

public Camera.Size getResolution() {
    return mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
}

public void takePicture(final String fileName) {
    this.mPictureFileName = fileName;
    // Postview and jpeg are sent in the same buffers if the queue is not empty when performing a capture.
    // Clear up buffers to avoid mCamera.takePicture to be stuck because of a memory issue
    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);

    // PictureCallback is implemented by the current class
    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, this);
}

@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    // The camera preview was automatically stopped. Start it again.
    mCamera.startPreview();
    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);

    // Write the image in a file (in jpeg format)
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mPictureFileName);
        fos.write(data);
        fos.close();
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        Log.e("PictureDemo", "Exception in photoCallback", e);
    }

}

public void cameraRelease() {
    if(mCamera != null){
        mCamera.release();
    }
}
}
```

Please any one can help me, or suggest another way to start the Camera Flash.
Thank you in Advanced.

Comment: yes as follow : 01-06 13:45:18.292 15148-15148/org.opencv.samples.facedetect E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.opencv.samples.facedetect/org.opencv.samples.facedetect.FdActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by applying this class from this link [Using Camera LED Flash with OpenCV on Android](http://www.azar.in/questions/2501776/using-camera-led-flash-with-opencv-on-android)

it's just worked perfectly :)

Here is the Class that i've implemented:

```
private static final String TAG = "Sample::Tutorial2View";

private Context my reference;

private static boolean isFlashLightON = false;

public Tutorial2View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
super(context, attrs);
this.myreference = context;
}

public List<String> getEffectList() {
return mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedColorEffects();
}

public boolean isEffectSupported() {
return (mCamera.getParameters().getColorEffect() != null);
}

public String getEffect() {
return mCamera.getParameters().getColorEffect();
}

public void setEffect(String effect) {
Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
params.setColorEffect(effect);
mCamera.setParameters(params);
}

public List<Size> getResolutionList() {
return mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
}

public void setResolution(Size resolution) {
disconnectCamera();
mMaxHeight = resolution.height;
mMaxWidth = resolution.width;
connectCamera(getWidth(), getHeight());
}

public Size getResolution() {
return mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
}

// Setup the camera
public void setupCameraFlashLight() {
Camera  camera = mCamera;
if (camera != null) {
Parameters params = camera.getParameters();

if (params != null) {
    if (isFlashLightON) {
        isFlashLightON = false;
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();
    } else {
        isFlashLightON = true;
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();

        }
    }
}

}
```